# Python - Non-Scrolling/Multi Display Bash?

Tags: python

Using Python, I have 12 scripts running in async at 2 processes at a time. When these two processes are running, they're printing constant information about each step they're taking.

What I'd like to do is be able to display my bash window in two separate parts. At the top, I'd like a task list/completed list that barely moves or changes. Eg

```
Async Process 1: Started.
Async Process 2: Started.
Async Process 2: Finished.
```

Then at the bottom of the bash, I'd like to display what these processes are printing out. I've seen a bunch of applications that has these capabilities inside a bash window, but couldn't find any python examples. What's the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Curses is the way to go for this one.  If you're ever looking to just have the bottom line update, it can be simpler to just not print a newline and then output an '\r' character to start at the beginning.  For example, `print('one', end='')` then `print('\rtwo', end='')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reccomend the [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module. Most non trivial terminal applications uses a curses or curses-like library to implement their UI.

Answer (score 1):

The unix environment has a lot of built in features that allow for this kind of monitoring.

Here's a quick and dirty solution:

submit the jobs from the command line bash prompt redirecting all the output that would be displayed to the screen to a common file(in append mode).

```
bash>  python script.py arg1 arg2 >> temp.out
bash>  python script.py arga argb >> temp.out
bash>  python script.py argx argy >> temp.out
..
bash>  python script.py arg1 arg2 >> temp.out
```

after all jobs are submitted and running, in the same terminal, you can monitor which ones are still running/completed with the "jobs" built in bash command

```
bash>  jobs
```

then open up a new terminal, and view what's going on(in realtime) in temp.out with "tail -f".  The output will be garbled from all the processes writing to it, but I'm guessing you'll still be able to make some sense of it.

```
bash>  tail -f temp.out
```

It's not as fancy as building your own process monitor, but the entire procedure shouldn't take more than 1 minute to set up.